# Different behaviors between the same var name and function name VS two same function name

Tags: javascript, function, var, variable-declaration, hoisting

Recently, I received this interview question, I know it's weird to declare var name and function name the same, but the code runs without errors, and I don't know how to explain this behavior, hence the question.

---

In the Chrome console, the following code logs `1`:

```js
var foo = function () {
  console.log(1)
}
function foo() {
  console.log(2)
}
foo()
```

And the following code logs `2`:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(1)
}
function foo() {
  console.log(2)
}
foo()
```

Why are the results not the same?

Comment: The question seems entirely moot as these are both something you should never, ever do. That being said, I would assume the difference is due to order of declaration being handled internally between explicit functions and function expressions.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, this is something I'll never do since eslint giving errors, but it's given by an interviewer and I honestly don't know how to explain this.

Comment: Understood - that context makes more sense.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not so many people know variable assignments [are not hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73763526/7881859), I think it's still a worthy question ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function declarations, including the assignment of their values, are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). Variable assignments are not.

In the first case, the function declaration for `foo` is hoisted so is overwritten by the variable assignment even though that appears earlier in the source order.